# Why does ruby return only the last match of the regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex

My regular expression is the following `(\d+_)*` and the test string is `1_2_3_`.  Ruby is matching the string correctly.  However the matchdata only returns "3_" as the match.

e.g.

```
irb(main):004:0> /(\d+_)*/.match("1_2_3_")
=> #<MatchData "1_2_3_" 1:"3_">
```

I'd expect something like  `#<MatchData "1_2_3_" 1:"1_", 2:"2_", 3:"3_">`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each new repetition of the group overwrites the previous match. All regex engines work that way. To my knowledge, only the .NET regex engine provides a means to access all the matches of a repeated group (a so-called "capture").

Imagine what's happening. In a regex, every pair of parentheses builds a capturing group; they are numbered from left to right. So in `/(\d+_)*/`, `(\d+_)` is capturing group number 1.

Now if you apply that regex to `1_2_`, what happens?

- `(\d+_)` matches `1_`
- `1_` is stored as the contents of the first capturing group. You could now access `\1` to see these contents.
- The `*` tells the regex engine to retry the match from the current position.
- `(\d+_)` now matches `2_`
- That text, `2_`, again needs to be stored in group number 1/backreference `\1`. So it overwrites whatever is in there.

To get the desired result in Ruby, you need to do two regex matches: `/(?:\d+_)*/` for the overall match and `/\d+_/` for each single match:

```
irb(main):001:0> s = "1_2_3_"
=> "1_2_3_"
irb(main):009:0> s.match(/(?:\d+_)*/)
=> #<MatchData "1_2_3_">
irb(main):007:0> s.scan(/\d+_/)
=> ["1_", "2_", "3_"]
```

Comment: +1, as it explains why the match result only returns the last match.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, Tim.  Any particular reason why all the regex engines work this way?  Seems a bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: @R.D. I hope my explanation clarifies this a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want `.scan`. It'll return an array of the matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
"1_2_3_".scan(/\d+_/) # =>  ["1_", "2_", "3_"]
```

will get you what you are looking for. (notice the removal of the `*`). I also removed the grouping b/c it simply results in an array of arrays, i.e `[["1_"], ["2_"], ["3_"]]`